# Error avoidance when socket communication on unity

Tags: c#, sockets, unity-game-engine

I am trying to receive socket communication with C # on Unity.

The following unityRecieve.cs will result in an error if Send.py is interrupted.

**Send.py**

```
import socket
import random

    HOST = '127.0.0.1'
    PORT = 50007

    client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    while True:
　　a = random.randrange(3)
　　result = str(a)
　　print(a)
　　client.sendto(result.encode('utf-8'),(HOST,PORT))
　　time.sleep(2.0)
```

**unityRecieve.cs**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;

public class unityRecieve : MonoBehaviour
{

    static UdpClient udp;

    void Start()
    {
        int LOCA_LPORT = 50007;

        udp = new UdpClient(LOCA_LPORT);
        udp.Client.ReceiveTimeout = 100;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        IPEndPoint remoteEP = null;
        byte[] data = udp.Receive(ref remoteEP);
        string text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);
        Debug.Log(text);
    }
}
```

https://jump1268.hatenablog.com/entry/2018/11/25/143459

How can I make unitiRecieve.cs keep running without giving an error message when Send.py is interrupted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if you have considered exception handling. If you did not, this might point you in the right direction.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/try-catch